# How is the kurtosis on the Cullen and Frey graph in the R package fitsidtrplus calculated?

Tags: r, distributions, skewness, kurtosis

I am using the package fitdistrplus in R to fit distributions to my data. My first step was to check my data against the Cullen and Frey graph that is produced using the descdist function. This is result I get:
[image]

However, when I independently calculate the skewness and kurtosis of my data (using the agricolae or e1071 packages), I obtain:

skewness = 0.424;
kurtosis = -0.900

The skewness matches, as 0.424^2 = 0.179, which is what is plotted. However, the descdist tool is outputting kurtosis = 2.0994 (as seen on the plot). How is this value obtained, and why is it different?

Comment: Have a look at the help page of `descdist`. There, the authors say: "[...] by default unbiased estimations of skewness and Pearsons's kurtosis values are printed (Sokal and Rohlf, 1995)." You can also look at the formulas they implemented by typing `descdist` in the R console such that the source code of the function is displayed (note that the parentheses have been omitted).

Comment: The function `kurtosis(x, type = 2)` from the `e1071` package returns the unbiased *excess* kurtosis (it subtracts $3$). The `descdist` function calculates the kurtosis, withouth subtracting $3$. Hence: $-0.900 + 3 = 2.1$ which is in agreement with the output of `descdist`. In the plot, you see that the normal distribution has a theoretical kurtosis of $3$.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! This was very helpful.